# Regular Expressions and Javascript and Phone Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how to use a regular expression to validate a phone number in Javascript.

So far my thoughts are to get the value when the form is submitted, and compare them to a regular expression. How would I go about doing that in Javascript? My pseudo-code so far looks sorta like this:

```
phoneVal = document.getElementById("phone");

if (phoneVal == \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}) {
    return True;
}
else if (phoneVal == \d{10}) {
    <string methods to add hyphens to an unbroken number>
    return True;
}
```

etc, etc

Does this look correct?

EDIT: How would I deal with parenthesis while in an if statement?

For example, /(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}/, only it'd be inside of if( ) so there might be a parsing problem?

Comment: You are comparing DOM element to regular expression's object.

Comment: Regarding your edit: parentheses have a special meaning in regular expressions -- they're used for grouping and capturing -- so `/(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}/.test(...)` is equivalent to `/\d{3} \d{3}-\d{4}/.test(...)`. To match actual parentheses around the area code, you want `/\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/.test(...)`. But to answer the actual question, regex literals `/.../` are a lot like string literals `"..."`: as long as the parser can tell you're inside a regex literal, it won't try to interpret its contents as code.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Nice to know. And I remember parenthesis being used in a similar way in Python regular expressions (Python was my first language), but I didn't see anything like that with Javascript. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does look correct, as pseudo-code; the actual JavaScript syntax for a regex-test is:

```
if(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(phoneVal))
```

(Notice the `^` and `$`; without them, it will match even if `phoneVal` merely contains a phone number as a substring.)

That said, I'm not sure that this part:

```
<string methods to add hyphens to an unbroken number>
```

is useful. You'll want to re-perform all of your validations and normalizations on the server-side, anyway, where you can *guarantee* that they actually take place; the only benefit of client-side JavaScript validation is to present error-messages in a more user-friendly way when possible. Without seeing the rest of your application, I can't say for sure, but I would *guess* that there's no real benefit in adding hyphens in this client-side code.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll just write a Javascript error if they put in some gibberish, but if it's a valid form of a phone number, I'll modify it server-side. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
phoneVal = document.getElementById("phone");

if (/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(phoneVal)) {
    return True;
}
else if (/\d{10}/.test(phoneVal )) {
    // <string methods to add hyphens to an unbroken number>
    return True;
}
```

or

```
return /\d{10}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(phoneVal )
```